# Login request in Facebook iframe tab page

Tags: facebook

I have a custom app that is installed as a tab on my fan page. This app is only meant to be installed on my fan page.  I want to get the user's Facebook ID to ensure that they are only voting once. I want the user's experience to be within the page tab (!) and not the application canvas.
How do I check user's facebook id and request login if he is not logged in? JavaScript SDK seems best solution here, but it doesn't seem to work.

So far I found this: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=91240. I pasted it to my app, but when I click on the button no login dialog appear.  Any help would be much appreciated.

-Ryan